# Exiting loop using regular expression in Perl

Tags: perl

I am appending information to a text file and want to do this until exit is entered as a string.

This is what I used but 'exit' does not want to exit the loop.

```
print "please input info to write to the file\n";
my $input = <STDIN>; 
until($input =~ /exit/)
{
    open MYFILE, ">>information.txt" or die "$!";
print MYFILE "$input";

print "enter 'exit' to exitor add more info\n";
my $input = <STDIN>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a few mistakes here, but as parapura said, only one causes this particular bug.

```
print "Please input info to write to the file\n";
my $input = <STDIN>; 
#Three argument open is better than a global filehandle
open (my $handle, '>>', 'information.txt') or die "$!";
until($input =~ /^exit$/) { #Better with ^$, else 'fireexit' will end the loop as well.
    print $handle $input;
    print "Enter 'exit' to exit or add more info\n";
    #Remove the 'my', else it is another variable than the one in the until clause
    $input = <STDIN>;
}
close ($handle) or die "$!";
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file anew every time through the loop?  Plus you didn’t close the file, which means you lose error checking. Your overly-hyped autovivved handles do not do that for you! And you should not write `"$input"` when you mean `$input`. And you forgot to check for eof.

Comment: Thanks @tchrist! I've moved the open out of the loop, and put a close afterwards (one could maybe even add an if around that checks if the first line was not exit and skips the whole lot). Changed the "$input" too, but how do I check on eof on a file I'm writing? Disk full? Print or die?

Answer (score 2):

One of your **$input** is hiding the other one.  Remove the my from the second one.